# error TS2339: Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'Worksheet'. microsoft /Office-js

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

I have updated "@microsoft/office-js" from ^1.1.25 to "^1.1.70" and I'm trying to use comments in my angular project.
I have added CDN link in index.html file head tag of the project.
I want to use add() method of CommentCollection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.commentcollection?view=excel-js-preview

Kindly help to fix the error .

Comment: could you please share the error information? would you please try to use script lab to o validate, see if you could still see the error?

Comment: @Raymond Issue is fixed now. I deleted packages of my angular project and did a clean install and it worked